# Error, too many loops, page not loading

Tags: php, redirect, header, infinite-loop

I have a VPS in which I set up my prestashop, instead of displaying a prestashop page, I wanted to display a countdown, for user because my website will open in few month, so my website is available only for my IP Adress.

I have the following code in the index.php

On top, before the existing code, i Put that lines

```
    if (!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('109.209.81.188')))
{
  header('Location: http://www.ferocious-beast.com/bienvenue.html');
  exit;
}
```

In my main computer it works fine, when I try in my smartphone,
I have the following error

[image]

Anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: This is happening because of this `header('Location: http://www.ferocious-beast.com/bienvenue.html');` this condition also happening on your bienvenue.html that's why its again redirect to that page and creates the infinite redirection loop

Comment: so should I just rename the page ? In my bienvenue there is no the same code

Comment: what happen if you just remove the code.?
and it might have some htaccess issue

Comment: If I remove the code, all works fine, but it display the page I don't want to show to unable users

Comment: Why don't you change the maintenance page, and set the shop in maintenance?